Setting up connection config to send email with AWS SES in Airflow, seeing error socket.timeout: timed out
I'm not sure on how to do that, I see an example but that's using SendGrid and I'm not sure if I should then change my host:
export AIRFLOW_CONN_SMTP_DEFAULT='smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@smtp.sendgrid.net:587'

should I instead do:
AIRFLOW_CONN_SMTP_DEFAULT='smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@email-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:587'

and how do I add my 'smpt mail from' portion to this connection string?
With the current string I have (the 2nd airflow_conn) I keep seeing the following error:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 77, in execute
    send_email(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 59, in send_email
    return backend(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 120, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, conn_id=conn_id, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 231, in send_mime_email
    smtp_conn = _get_smtp_connection(smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_timeout, smtp_ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 263, in _get_smtp_connection
    smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1048, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1054, in _get_socket
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

